# In React-Native, how can I choose an assets folder instead of another one based on my environment file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, module

I'm building white label apps.

I have an assets folder that contains one images folder and one fonts folder for each brands.

Like so :

```
assets/
   brand1/
      fonts/
      images/
        img1.png
        img2.png
        img3.png
   brand2/
      fonts/
      images/
        img1.png
        img2.png
        img3.png
src/
```

My idea would be to have an index.js at the root of the assets folder where I'd be able to export the relevant set of folders based on my environment file.

Though I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Any hint ?

(My concern is that I don't want to have the environment conditioning in each of my components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that you have two environments;

.env.brand1 `NAME=BRAND1`
.env.brand2 `NAME=BRAND2`

create an `index.js` file, it's code should look something like this;

```
const images = {
    BRAND1: {
        logo: require('./brand1/brand1Logo.jpeg')
    },
    BRAND2: {
        logo: require('./brand2/brand2Logo.jpeg')
    }

}

export default images;
```

You can now use image in any file like this;

```
... other imports
import images from '#assets/index'

export default function () {
    
    ...other code 

    <Image source={images[Config.NAME].logo} />

}
```

[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a js script(scriptName.js) that moves your folder for one project to a base code, here is an example:

```
// Import necessary modules
const fs = require('fs-extra');

// Determine the app environment based on the script name
const scriptName = process.argv[2];
let assetFolder;

if (scriptName === 'project1') {
  assetFolder = './project1/assets';
} else if (scriptName === 'project2') {
  assetFolder = './project2/assets';
} else {
  console.error(
    'Invalid script name. Please provide "project1" or "project2" as argument.',
  );
  process.exit(1);
}

// Use the determined folders for the build
console.log('Script Name:', scriptName);
console.log('assetFolder:', assetFolder);
fs.copySync(assetFolder, './src/assets');
```

And run it with node 'theNemeOfYourScript'.js project1

Put a script to a root directory And make your directory structure like this:

```
project1
  -assets
    -someFile
project2
  -assets
    -someFile
src
  -assets
-`You can put a dummy file for initial`
```

And use imorts as you would usually use them as import * from 'src/assets/someFile'